# How to get the same width as the CSS media query checks against

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It seems like the `isTablet` function returns true at later point. Why, and how do I fix it so isTablet says it is a tablet when the CSS media query does.

```
function isTablet() {
    return $(window).width() >= 768;
}
```

and

```
<link href="css/tablet-default.css" media="all and (min-width: 768px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want the device-width in your media query?otherwise changing the window size may toggle you in and out of the display.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hard coding the width in the `isTablet` function (following [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), you could check for the state of an element that changes due to the media queries.

For example, if you have an element which is normally `display: none` but has `display: block` for tablets, have `isTablet` check the visibly of that element instead.

Answer (score 0):

The .width() function does not include paddings or margins.

http://api.jquery.com/width/

That may be the difference you are noticing.